# Как реализовать задачу на JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы

> В данном массиве представлено меню завтрака в отеле.
> Шеф-повар решил заменить один из пунктов на "Fluffy Pancakes".
> Напишите программу, которая возьмет индекс в качестве вводных данных, заменит элемент с этим индексом на "Fluffy Pancakes" и выведет в консоль новое меню.
>
> **Пример вводных данных**
> 2
>
> **Пример результата**
>
> ```
> [
> 'Cinnamon Doughnuts',
> 'Waffles',
> 'Fluffy Pancakes',
> 'Chorizo Burrito',
> 'French Toast'
> ]
> ```
>
> ```
> function main() {
>     var breakfasts = ['Cinnamon Doughnuts', 'Waffles', 'Granola', 'Chorizo Burrito', 'French Toast'];
>     var index = parseInt(readLine(), 10)
>    
>     //замените соответствующий элемент на "Fluffy Pancakes"
>     
>     //выведите меню в консоль
> ```

Пробовал через

```
breakfasts = breakfasts.concat
```

Не помогает, не врубаюсь как реализовать данную задачу

Comment: кто такой readLine? и причём тут concat? и что вообще по вашему значит `breakfasts.concat` ?

Comment: Я сначала решил, что можно добавить элемент к массиву, чтоб при рандомном вводе юзера это бы сработало, но увы :(

Answer (score 3):

Можно конечно использовать метод splice ,но зачем если мы заменяем один элемент на другой.
Вот самый простой варинат.

```js
const company = "Fluffy Pancakes"
function main() {
    var breakfasts = ['Cinnamon Doughnuts', 'Waffles', 'Granola', 'Chorizo Burrito', 'French Toast'];
    var index = parseInt(prompt('Введите число'))
    breakfasts[index] = company
    console.log(breakfasts)
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

в массивах js есть встроенный метод .splice
вкратце, берет элемент по индексу, может удалять и втсавлять в нужное место
подробнее [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice][1]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать метод `splice` для массивов (дока https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Он позволяет не только вырезать ненужный элемент, но и вставить какие-либо данный внутрь

```js
let breakfasts = ['Cinnamon Doughnuts', 'Waffles', 'Granola', 'Chorizo Burrito', 'French Toast'];
breakfasts.splice(2, 1, 'Fluffy Pancakes')

console.log(breakfasts)
```

В коде выше из массива удалится 1 элемент по индексу 2 и вставится 'Fluffy Pancakes'

Более простой вариант как советуют в комментариях:

```js
let breakfasts = ['Cinnamon Doughnuts', 'Waffles', 'Granola', 'Chorizo Burrito', 'French Toast'];
breakfasts[2] = 'Fluffy Pancakes'

console.log(breakfasts)
```

Answer (score 0):

вот решение

```
function main() {
    var breakfasts = ['Cinnamon Doughnuts', 'Waffles', 'Granola', 'Chorizo Burrito', 'French Toast'];
    var index = parseInt(readLine(), 10)
   
    //замените соответствующий элемент на "Fluffy Pancakes"
    breakfasts[index]= "Fluffy Pancakes";
    //выведите меню в консоль
    console.log(breakfasts)
}
```